# Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse using Spring boot and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is get the response from spring boot rest api and the returned object is a Pojo
and trying to parse it and than print id of that bean it is printing everything is correct but it is showing error

```
home:38 
VM111:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (home:39)
```

Code

```
function sendGet(){    
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/api/getemp");
    request.onreadystatechange=function(){
        console.log(this.response);
        var employee=this.response;
        console.log(employee);
        var ee=JSON.parse(employee);
        console.log(ee);
        console.log(ee.id);
    };
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: You have an error @ `http://localhost:8080/api/getemp` and that page isproducing HTML output.

Comment: Could you please attach the console log of `employee`?

Comment: Please refrain from using `var`, use `const` or `let` instead.

Comment: If your api retruning json data directly why you are parsing it ?